# PDF support on OpenOffice.org programs

Tags: pdf, openoffice

Does OpenOffice.org have PDF capability?

Can I fill in a form or scan to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenOffice, without (fairly alpha) plugins, does little more than export to PDF. If you want to scan to PDF, use your scanner's included scanning utility or [Simple Scan](https://launchpad.net/simple-scan) on Linux. Virtually all scanning programs have a PDF function.

Adobe Acrobat Reader will fill out forms fine.